# Why does atq not list jobs in either queue order, or chronological order?

Tags: centos, at

```
sudo atq
7   Wed Nov 15 13:46:00 2017 a root
6   Sun Oct 15 13:45:00 2017 a root
8   Fri Dec 15 13:46:00 2017 a root
9   Mon Jan 15 13:47:00 2018 a root
```

Why would running `atq` not list the jobs either in the order they were issued to `at` (6,7...n) *or* in chronological order of when the job should run (Oct, Nov...etc)?

If it matters, I ran this on a CentOS 7.3 box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atq` lists jobs by [listing the directory containing them](https://sources.debian.net/src/at/3.1.20-3/at.c/#L594), without sorting; so jobs end up listed in directory order.

You will see the same order with

```
sudo ls -lU /var/spool/at
```

(or `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` for other readers on Debian-based systems).